# AJAX returning 404 Not Found in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

This is my route and I want to post the data through ajax but it gives me the 404 not found error

```
Route::post('{req_id}/com/{id}','CompanyController@store');
```

This is my Ajax code in view

```
 $('#body_tb tr td a').click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var req_id = {{$req_id}}

        $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url :req_id+"/com/"+id,

            data :{
                _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                company_id : id,
                req : req_id
            },
            success: function(data) {

            }

        });

    });
```

This is Controller

```
 public function store($id)
{

    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative path, eg. `url: '/' + req_id + '/com/' + id`

Comment: @ArsalanAkram Check the sent request URL in your dev tool and make sure it's ok.

Comment: try `'{{ url($req_id.'/com') }}/'+id`

Answer (score -1):

Change your method in the controller:

```
public function store($req_id, $id)
{
    print_r($_POST);
    exit();
}
```

The method needs all of the parameters of the route in order. `$req_id` is missing in yours.